# How to make a window transparent by clicking a program's title bar?

Tags: transparency

In an earlier version of Ubuntu with Compiz I'm pretty sure there was a useful setting to enable seeing what's behind the current window by clicking and holding the title bar, which then changed the current window's opacity to something like 10 percent.

Is there any way to achieve this in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Was it the Opacity plug in?, because that it's still in Compiz in 11.10.

Comment: I looked at both the Opacify and the Opacity, Brightness, etc. plugins in Compiz but could not see a way to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://launchpad.net/~unity-team/+archive/compiz-testing

add this to your sources.list

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/compiz-testing/ubuntu oneiric main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/compiz-testing/ubuntu oneiric main

Or

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding `ppa:unity-team/compiz-testing` to your system's Software Sources

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-main
```

you will also want to add this

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```